# php email script for just email address

Tags: php, flash, email

Im new to this PHP stuff so please excuse my ignorance

Im after having just one input text box in my flash website where a person just enters there email address and at the click of a button it sends an email to me to a pre defined email address with a predefined subject heading and the email address that was entered in the body of the email

Anyone know of any links or can give some help

all the ones i have found want names email subject message and so on

Any help is appreciated
Mark

EDIT

ok I have the following

In flash I have an input text converted to a movieclip called "addy". Inside the movie clip which has the inputbox which has the variable name "emailaddy"

A Button called "email"

The code i Have running when "email" is clicked is

```
on (release) {

form.loadVariables("email.php", "POST");
}
```

the email.php script is as follows

```
<?php
$sendTo = "mark@here.co.uk";
$subject = "Subscribe to Website";
$headers = "From: Website";
$headers .= "<" . $_POST["addy"] . ">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["addy"] . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: " . $_POST["addy"];
$message = "Please Subscribe me to Website";
mail(recipient, subject, message, other headers);
mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

when I click the button nothing happens

what im after is when the button is clicked for and email to be sent in the following format

To: "mark@here.co.uk"
From: email address specified in text field "addy"
Subject: "Subscribe to Website";
body: "Please subscribe me to Website"

Your help is greatly appreciated

mark

Comment: What's wrong with using `mail()`?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/flash_php_email.htm).. Even source code is available..

Comment: more customizeable methid https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help:

```
<?php
$user_mail=$_POST["mail"]; //or $user_mail=$_GET["mail"]; Set to your convenience! 
$to_mail="abcde@xyz.com"; //Change to your email address
$message="New user's Email: ".$user_mail; //Change to your requirements
$subject="New user registered"; //Change to your preferred subject
$from="registration@yourwebsite.com"; //Change to your website mail id 
mail($to_mail,$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
```

To know more about the [`mail`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function, please see [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Answer (score 0):

Well in depth you can do like this

```
<?php
if($_POST){

$userEmail = $_POST0["emailaddy"]; // textbox variable name comes here
$to      = 'abc@xyz.com'; //write down here your email
$subject = 'Subscribe to website'; // your subject goes here
$message = 'Please Subscribe me to Website'; // Mail body message
$headers = 'From: ' . $userEmail . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: ' . $userEmail . "\r\n" .
    'Return-Path: ' . $userEmail; //can send x-Mailer also

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}else{
echo "Invalid Request";
return false;
}
```

Don't forget to check first $_POST is happened or not. No need to send Return-path instead of this use x-Mailer which sound good for other mail service providers.

To know more about this read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to an SMTP server ,like Postfix or gmail there is a neat php library called PhpMailer.

It is well documentated, so you should be good to go by googleing it :)